# structure of flat modules over a DVR

Tags: flatness, projective-modules

I. Kaplansky has proved that if a torsion free module (over a complete DVR)  is countably generated and does not contains infinitely divisible elements then it is free.

Is there any analog of this result for modules over an arbitrary DVR?

Comment: Read the answers at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302007/r-a-dvr-with-fraction-field-k-what-are-the-r-submodules-of-kn/302066#302066